# Two Files icons in Ubuntu 20.04 application launcher

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, 20.04, filemanager

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. After upgrading I found that there are two '*Files*' icons in the application launcher. One seems to look like the earlier one and the other feels modern.
[image]

Should I remove the earlier one? Or should I keep both?

```
$ apt policy nautilus
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
$ which nautilus
/usr/bin/nautilus
```

I'm not getting the output of `ls ~/.local/share/applications | grep -i nautilus`.

Output of `find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H 'Name=Files' {} \; 2>/dev/null` is:

```
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:Name=Files 
/usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop:Name=Files 
/usr/share/applications/csd-automount.desktop:Name=Files
```

Comment: This time a small image of the two Files would be helpful!

Comment: You could [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy nautilus` and `which nautilus` and  `ls ~/.local/share/applications | grep -i nautilus`

Comment: @DKBose done with the edits

Comment: Do you have anything at all in `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: @DKBose yes `$ ls ~/.local/share/applications
jetbrains-studio.desktop
mimeapps.list
mimeinfo.cache
org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GSConnect.desktop
org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GSConnect.Preferences.desktop
vsls-launcher.desktop
`

Comment: Okay, then I'm out of ideas! Maybe someone more familiar with this system will be able to help.

Comment: I have added the image. Sorry to be late.

Comment: Do a search for any .desktop file on your system that contains Files as the name: `find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H 'Name=Files' {} \; 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Your image shows desktop icons. I understood the launcher to be the vertical (or horizontal) bar containing icons. Right-click on each of them and see if you can glean something from their properties.

Comment: @DKBose what you were referring to is `Dock`. I clicked on view details but it only redirected me to the Software centre.

Comment: @vanadium I couldn't get you

Comment: This bash command finds and lists all .desktop files that contain 'Name=Files'. So it will allow you to identify the duplicate .desktop file.

Comment: @vanadium i got output as `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:Name=Files
/usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop:Name=Files
/usr/share/applications/csd-automount.desktop:Name=Files
`

Comment: Place this essential information about launchers on your system in your question. Use edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments the following information on .desktop files on your system:

```
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:Name=Files
/usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop:Name=Files
/usr/share/applications/csd-automount.desktop:Name=Files
```

it is clear that you also have a different file manager installed, "Nemo", or at least had it installed at one time. Anyway, its desktop file is still there.

One .desktop file is for file manager `nautilus`, the default file manager on an Ubuntu desktop. The other .desktop file is for `nemo`, a different file manager used as default in the Cinnamon desktop.

To avoid having two files icons, either

- Remove `nemo` (never remove your default file manager), which will remove the .desktop file
- If you wish to keep `nemo`, you can change the name of its icon by editing the .desktop file, so you can easily distinguish the icons.

To change the name of the icon for `nemo`:

1. Copy the file `/usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop` to the folder `.local/share/applications` in your home directory.
2. Edit the copy with your text editor and change `Name=Files` to, for example, `Name=Nemo File Manager`.
3. Save the file and close the editor.

The changed copy of the `nemo.desktop` file will override the system wide one. Accordingly, that icon will now appear as "Nemo File Manager".

Comment: thanks man, it worked. I applied the process and restarted the system. can you tell me how I can swap the icons?

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I had two `nautilus` but indeed `nemo` was somehow also installed.