# Remove Old Nautilus Icon

Tags: nautilus, nemo

I cam across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231303/two-files-icons-in-ubuntu-20-04-application-launcher) thread on having two icons for Files. I am frustrated by having two icons, one for Nautilus and one for Nemo to manage Files. This explains how to change the names of the icons, but if I only want to use Nemo, how can I remove the other icon from showing up at all?

Answer (score 0):

To do it the safe way, i.e. without directly altering your system files, copy the `.desktop` file represented by the icon that you do not want to see to your local `.local/share/applications` folder as indicated in [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231303/two-files-icons-in-ubuntu-20-04-application-launcher). Add, or edit the existing line if present, to read

```
Hidden=true
```

This causes the launcher to be fully ignored, as if it did not exist.